# Cordova Plugins does not schedule a local notification on an iOS App built on PhoneGap

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, schedule, localnotification

I'm trying to package a native iOS App using PhoneGap platform. I've added the Cordova library in the config.xml file for the local notification.

I want to schedule two daily notifications (one morning and one evening). When I alert window.plugin.notification.local.add ({ message: 'Great app!' }), it works. However, when the App is loaded, window.plugin.notification.local.add for only evening show up in the tablet notification even though I set the custom date and time for both of them...

Also, cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule function does not work.

My questions are
1- Why cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule function does not trigger anything?
2- Why window.plugin.notification.local.add does not schedule the morning notification?
3- What is the difference between cordova.plugins and window.plugin?

I appreciate if anyone can assist me on this...

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function() { init(); }, 500);//1/2 seconds
 //
function init() { 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
 //alert('hello matt');
    // Now safe to use the Cordova API
 //window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'Great app3!' });
 //user premission
 window.plugin.notification.local.promptForPermission();

 //
 var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(10);
  d.setMinutes(0);
  d.setSeconds(0);

 window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:         1,  // A unique id of the notifiction
    date:       d,    // This expects a date object
    message:    'Make sure to check Today’s Metric Insight for powerful tools that will help to transform you into the most fit, energetic, healthiest version of yourself. ',  // The message that is displayed
    title:      'TheBigPicture',  // The title of the message
    repeat:     'daily',  // Either 'secondly', 'minutely', 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly' or 'yearly'
    autoCancel: true, // Setting this flag and the notification is automatically canceled when the user clicks it
});
 /*
 badge:      Number,  // Displays number badge to notification
    sound:      String,  // A sound to be played
    json:       String,  // Data to be passed through the notification
 ongoing:    Boolean, // Prevent clearing of notification (Android only)
*/
//

var d2 = new Date();
  d2.setHours(19);
  d2.setMinutes(0);
  d2.setSeconds(0);
  
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:         2,  // A unique id of the notifiction
    date:       d2,    // This expects a date object
    message:    'Make sure to update your daily Accountability Tracker, and complete your 100 Day Challenge daily survey. ',  // The message that is displayed
    title:      'TheBigPicture',  // The title of the message
    repeat:     'daily',  // Either 'secondly', 'minutely', 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly' or 'yearly'
    autoCancel: true, // Setting this flag and the notification is automatically canceled when the user clicks it
});  
  
 //window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'Great app!' });
 
  cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule([{
                    id: 1,
     title: 'TheBigPicture',
                    text: 'Make sure to check Today’s Metric Insight. ',
     at: _10_am,
     every: 'day'
                }, {
                    id: 2,
     title: 'TheBigPicture',
                    text: 'Make sure to update your daily Accountability Tracker.',
     at: _7_pm,
     every: 'day'
                }]);
//
cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("schedule", function(notification) {
    alert('fourth');
    alert("scheduled: " + notification.id);
});


}//end of onDeviceReady function
//

    </script>



<script>
```